# $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\tan^3(3x) \cdot (5^{x^{2}} - 1)}$ without using L'Hospital or Taylor's series

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

Find limit without using L'Hospital or Taylor's series:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\tan^3(3x) \cdot (5^{x^{2}} - 1)}$$

---

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\tan^3(3x) \cdot (5^{x^{2}} - 1)} = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\sin(2x^5)} \cdot \frac{\sin(2x^5)}{\tan^3(3x) \cdot (5^{x^{2}} - 1)} = $$

$$= \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\sin(2x^5)} \cdot \frac{\sin(2x^5)}{x^5} \cdot \frac{x^2}{5^{x^{2}} - 1} \cdot \frac{ x^3}{\tan^3(3x)}$$

- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\sin(2x^5)} = 1$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(2x^5)}{x^5} = 2$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{5^{x^{2}} - 1} = \frac{1}{\ln5}$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ x^3}{\tan^3(3x)} = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \cos^3(3x) \cdot \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3}{\sin^3(3x)} = 1 \cdot \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^3 = \frac{1}{27}$

We get:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\tan^3(3x) \cdot (5^{x^{2}} - 1)} = 1 * 2 * \frac{1}{\ln5} * \frac{1}{27} = \frac{2}{27 \ln5}$$

All credits to @Bernard. Thank you all, question closed.

Comment: Welcom to MSE :). The limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\sin(2x^5)}$ is 1. Why do you think that is undefined? :)

Comment: You have an error: $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}x=1$.

Comment: @Bernard you are right. I've edited that. Thank you.

Comment: @Ixion Thank you. I have no idea. That's the whole problem. I was sure it is 1 but Desmos plotter says it is undefined.

Comment: I see, remember that by the definition of limit, you don't care what happens to the function at $x_0=0$. Desmos plotter is a good app, but your brain is better ;).

Comment: Anyway, try to solve the original limit, using the equality $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\sin(2x^5)}=1$. You can do it.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying. I think now I have better chances. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comments.

Comment: No. It has been solved by @Bernard and then I modified his answer to fit my constrains (I couldn't use derivatives). I wrote that modified version of answer in original question. The effect that you see above is a product of work done by me, Bernard and people commenting - mostly by Bernard (that's why his answer is accepted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using equivalents and some standard limits: rewrite  the fraction as
$$\frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\sin(2x^5)}\frac{\sin(2x^5)}{\tan^3(3x)} \cdot \frac{x^2}{(5^{x^{2}} - 1)}\cdot\frac1{x^2}.$$
By substitution, the first factor tends to $1$. Also by substitution, $\:\dfrac{5^{x^2}-1}{x^2}$ tends to the derivative of $5^x$ at $0$, i.e. $\ln 5$.
Last, $\sin(2x^5)\sim_0 2x^5$ and $\tan 3x)\sim_03x$, so $\tan^3(3x)\sim_0(3x)^3=27x^3$, and ultimately we obtain the equivalence
$$\frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))}{\sin(2x^5)}\frac{\sin(2x^5)}{\tan^3(3x)} \cdot \frac{x^2}{(5^{x^{2}} - 1)}\cdot\frac1{x^2}\sim_0\frac{2\not x^5}{27\not x^3\cdot\ln5\cdot \not x^2}=\frac 2{27\ln 5}.$$

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. Unfortunately I can't use your idea since I can't use derivatises to calculate limits yet. Sorry, I didn't mention that in my post simply because I didn't even know it can be done.

Comment: But you mentioned in your question the limit of $\frac{x^2}{5^{x^{2}} - 1}$??

Comment: Yeah, cause I found it on Wikipedia page of elementary limits. Is it obtained by derivatives?

Comment: Almost all standard limits used in this computation correspond to the  limit of a rate of variation, which is the general definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight variant on Bernard's answer: rewrite the fraction as

$${\ln(1+\sin(2x^5))\over\sin(2x^5)}\cdot{\sin(2x^5)\over2x^5}\cdot\left(3x\over\sin(3x)\right)^3\cdot{x^2\ln5\over e^{x^2\ln5}-1}\cdot{2\cos^3(3x)\over3^3\ln5}$$

then use the familiar limits

$$\lim_{u\to0}{\ln(1+u)\over u}=\lim_{u\to0}{\sin u\over u}=\lim_{u\to0}{e^u-1\over u}=1$$

to get the limit

$$1\cdot1\cdot1^3\cdot1\cdot{2\cdot1^3\over27\ln5}={2\over27\ln5}$$

Comment: Yeah, I just got something simillar, without exp function. I will write that in a minute in my original question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your edit, which must have posted while I was composing my answer.

Comment: Yes, it was like 1sec apart, I think you got it first though :)